# Will using Jackson input stream bring all contents into memory

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a JSON (from stream). The data is huge. So I don't want to deserialize into a concrete Java Object. So I'm thinking to use Jackson parser.

```
JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
JsonParser  parser  = factory.createJsonParser(stream);
```

My goal is to get specific sections from stream(specific properties from the object)

```
{
    "array": [],
    "map": {},
    "bool": "true",
    "string": "abcd"
}
```

*For example:* I want to get only the map or the array and so on

However my question is when I use inputstream and parse it( to get specific sections of the stream) will it(the entire JSON) be brought into the memory all at once?

What is the difference between this(parsing) way and deserializing it into an object(and then getting the specific members from the object)?

Answer (score 0):

> Of 3 major processing modes that Jackson supports, Streaming Processing (also known as Incremental Processing) is the most efficient way to process JSON content. It has the lowest memory and processing overhead, and can often match performance of many binary data formats available on Java platform (see "Performance Comparison" link below)

According to fasterxml documentation ( http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonStreamingApi ), the `JsonParser` does not read all the stream in the memory. It only read the stream everytime it is needed.

Comment: If I use `JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readValue(src, JsonNode.class);` where `src` is stream, will it bring the entire JSON into memory?

Comment: Yes. Because jackson need to read the entire json to do the mapping with the given class.

Comment: So since I need direct acces to one the elements(`array` or `map`) do I need to use streaming(and not tree model)? ( I don't want to bring the entire JSON into memory)

Comment: If you don't want to grint the JSON into memory, you have to use the streaming API. That's the only way.